# Possessive apostrophe in this case (company listing designs in a particular range)

Tags: possessives, verb-agreement

If a company called Peter Jones (made up name!) has a range called Peter's Pals on their site and then wants to list the designs like this:
Peter's Pals Designs
Is this correct?
Should it be Peter's Pals' Designs

Or just easier to head is as Peter's Pals - Designs

Thanks

Comment: If you wear Nike sneakers, you do not wear Nike's sneakers. If you go to a Ford dealership, you see a bunch of Ford cars, not a bunch of Ford's cars. If there's a Microsoft Powerpoint presentation on your hard drive, it's not a Microsoft Powerpoint's presentation.

Comment: @RegDwigнt But the essential difference here is that the name of the organisation is not "Peter". It is "Peter Jones". (There is a shop by that name in a fashionable part of London). Personally, were it me, I would make it "Peter's Pals - Designs".

Comment: @WS2 I am not talking about the first possessive. And neither is the OP. We're all in complete agreement that the first possessive is fine.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Then I guess we are on the same page. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

*Peter's Pals Designs* is fine. *Designs by Peter's Pals* is also a possibility.

The brand name--or sub-brand name, if there is such a thing--is what it is, and it does not change.

Peter's Pals is not about pals, literally, but pals figuratively. For that matter, Peter's Pals is not about Peter, literally, but only about Peter as a brand name, which in this case is Peter's.

Take the brand name *Smothers Brothers*. (There are actually two brothers whose surname is Smothers, but as far as I know they are not in a business named Smothers Brothers, though Dick Smothers does have a wine-making business.) If the two brothers were in the wine-making business together, and they decided to name their company Smothers Brothers Wine, the same rule as above would apply. The brand name is what it is and is not inflected to show possession. The wine's brand name is simply Smothers Brothers.

If the vintners Smothers decided to have a sub-brand (or niche brand) such as Smothers Brothers Varietals, the same rule applies: No possessive is needed; their niche brand is Smothers Brothers Varietals. Other examples:

- *McCurdy Family Ford* (a car dealership) might have a niche brand called *McCurdy Family Ford Compacts* [i.e., compact cars], but not McCurdy Family Ford's Compacts.
- *Galaxy Sound*, a business involving retail sales of stereo components, might decide to branch out and create a specialty business within their stereo music reproduction and call it *Galaxy Sound Surround Systems* (for home theater customers). Again, there is no need to make *Sound* possessive.  -

Comment: This is a very well-reasoned answer. I'm surprised that no one upvote before now.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Thanks, Sven. Your compliment means a lot. Don

Answer (score 0):

Peter's Pals' designs is grammatically accurate. But I do not think that a company is often concerned with the finer points of grammar when they are in the business of selling. So long as the name gets the idea across, they're happy. Beside's some companies get creative with grammar and naming, almost as creative as some rappers do.

Comment: << Peter's Pals' designs >> is certainly acceptable. But it is seen as grammatically acceptable and often preferable to use (even plural-form) attributive rather than genitive constructions (thus 'the Writers Guild of America West', say). Lloyds Bank, the Lloyds branch on Market Street. But all covered on ELU long ago (probably about the time Waterstones ditched the apostrophe, recognising modern shifts).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Since the company is a design company, it's not surprising if they want to make a stylistic statement with their choice of name. That happens a great deal. But not really in this case as the name is pretty dull and prosaic. Not like Nike for wing'd victory.

Comment: I'm saying that << Peter's Pals' designs is grammatically accurate. >> is potentially misleading. << Waterstones outlets >> is equally grammatical. The attributive usage is in fact probably becoming the more common where personal possession is not being stressed. Thus << The dogs' home is ironically right next to the local dogs home. And behind the donkey sanctuary. >>